# result of .exec(function (err, result)) not showing a result, althought the entry is made to the database

Tags: sails.js

I'm trying to add a new user to the database and depending on the outcome of err and createdUser generate text for the frontend.

Somehow the field createdUser stays untouched, althought the entry is made to the db. What's wrong here?

Any help appreciated

```
User.create(req.body).exec(function (err, createdUser) {
           if (err != null)
             res.send({ 'message': err, 'user': 0 });
           else
             res.send({ 'message': "user created", 'user': createdUser });
         });
```

Comment: What version of sails are you using?

Comment: i'm using 1.0.1
DB is MongoDB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using Sails v1~, returning created, updated or destroyed records is not something that happens without implicitly including fetch as part of your request.

```
.meta({fetch: true})
```

For you example above, you can return the record by altering your code to

```
User.create(req.body).meta({fetch: true}).exec(function (err, createdUser) {
    if (err != null)
        res.send({ 'message': err, 'user': 0 });
    else
        res.send({ 'message': "user created", 'user': createdUser });
});
```

You can find out more about .fetch() or .meta({fetch: true}) [here](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/queries/fetch).